Data not getting deleted automatically or manually in TimescaleDB
I observe that data is not getting deleted from Timescale DB tables either automatically or manually. Here are my DDLs:
CREATE TABLE traffic
(
    src_ip_addr INET,
    ts          TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
);

CREATE INDEX ON traffic (ts);

SELECT public.create_hypertable('traffic', 'ts');
SELECT public.add_retention_policy('traffic', drop_after => INTERVAL '2 minute', schedule_interval => INTERVAL '1 minute');

In my table table I have rows with ts values ranging from 2024-07-31 13:41:20.611561 +00:00 to 2024-07-31 13:41:33.140070 +00:00.
According to Timescale, the chunk deletion should have happened because it last ran on 2024-07-31 13:53:49.294042 +00:00, but there's still data older than that time:



hypertable_name
job_id
config
schedule_interval
job_status
last_run_status
last_run_started_at
next_start
total_runs
total_successes
total_failures




traffic
1015
{"drop_after": "00:02:00", "hypertable_id": 6}
0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 1 mins 0.0 secs
Scheduled
Success
2024-07-31 13:53:49.294042 +00:00
2024-07-31 13:54:49.315476 +00:00
14
14
0



The data is not deleted even if I manually delete the chunks:
SELECT public.drop_chunks('traffic', INTERVAL '1 minute');

I think this is happening because range_end is tomorrow, but I'm not sure why that's the case if drop_after is 2 minutes.



hypertable_schema
hypertable_name
chunk_schema
chunk_name
primary_dimension
primary_dimension_type
range_start
range_end
range_start_integer
range_end_integer
is_compressed
chunk_tablespace
chunk_creation_time




traffic
traffic
_timescaledb_internal
_hyper_6_16_chunk
ts
timestamp with time zone
2024-07-25 00:00:00.000000 +00:00
2024-08-01 00:00:00.000000 +00:00
null
null
false
null
2024-07-31 13:41:20.614031 +00:00




You should read About Data Retention: Drop data by chunk.

Isn't that what I'm doing by manually dropping the chunks?

Read the docs about what that means, it is not what you think.

Can you confirm if the timezone you are using with both retention policy and table's ts column is same and not different?

Yes, they are the same.

I think you should explicit the chunk time interval. Also, the latest syntax you say by_range:
SELECT create_hypertable('traffic', by_range('ts', INTERVAL '1 minute'));

In this case, your chunk will have only 1 minute of data. You can remove the remaining data only when all the full minute is at least 1 minute old.
Another thing, is double check if background workers are not stuck: https://docs.timescale.com/use-timescale/latest/user-defined-actions/troubleshooting/

Thanks, by_range was missing.
